# MYSQL Query convert to SQLSERVER

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hi guys in currently working on a CODEIGNITER project the project was migrated from MYSQL to SQL SERVER 2014, regarding SQL SERVER 2014 i only know the basics.

I'm having a problem from about 2 weeks, i always try to search and search in order to fix things, but at this moment i'm consuming too much time trying to find how to solve this.

I have the following query on MYSQL

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as timestamp 
FROM (`module_items`) 
JOIN `module_items_news2` 
  ON `item_id` = `id` 
WHERE 
  `module_id` = '$module_id' 
  AND $this->site = 1 
GROUP BY 
  date_format(date, '%Y%m') 
ORDER BY 
  `date` DESC
```

The above code works fine for MySQL database.

I'm trying to convert this to SQL SERVER but i don't had UNIX_TIMESTAMP function on SQL SERVER. After creating a function and trying to modify the query

```
DECLARE @module_id VARCHAR(1)
SET @module_id = 3
SELECT *,dbo.UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as timestamp 
FROM module_items JOIN module_items_news2 ON item_id = id WHERE module_id = 
@module_id 
GROUP BY date_format(date, '%Y%m') 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Now i'm getting

```
'date_format' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

How can i proceed in order to make it work?

Kind Regards.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.  The code has multiple issues.  I doubt it even does what you intend in MySQL.

Comment: It won't work on SQL Server becasue it does not allow for non-aggregated columns in SELECT that are not in GROUP BY column list.

Comment: Try and tone down the capitalization. Not everything is an acronym or needs to be YELLED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but I suspect you want something like this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (SELECT . . . ,  -- list the columns explicitly
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) ORDER BY date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM module_items mi JOIN
           module_items_news2 min2 
           ON min2.item_id = mi.id
      WHERE module_id = @module_id 
     ) m
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

If you really need to convert a date to a unix timestamp, you can use:

```
DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01', date) as timestamp
```

This is rarely needed in SQL Server (which historically did not run on Unix systems).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `DATE_FORMAT()` in either version. Use

```
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

in both databases.